# iOS App Transport Security blocking http transfer from excepted domain

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I'm trying to configure ATS to allow http loads from my domain, but with the plist settings below it is still blocking access to image requests (but strangely, not to http 'POST' messages). If I enable Allow Arbitrary Loads it works fine. The code to get the images uses NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest with (e.g) url of http://www.my-domain.com/ImageStore/aFolder/bfolder/xyz.jpg. I am running from the emulator using latest updates. I can't find anyone else reporting a similar problem... what am I doing wrong?

Warning message:

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

info.plist settings:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>my-domain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubDomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly setting the  global setting for NSAppTransportSecurity. I have included a version that works in an app I have.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>my-domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

From the release notes for iOS 9.0

> [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html)
>
> App Transport Security (ATS) enforces best practices in the secure
>   connections between an app and its back end. ATS prevents accidental
>   disclosure, provides secure default behavior, and is easy to adopt; it
>   is also on by default in iOS 9 and OS X v10.11. You should adopt ATS
>   as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app
>   or updating an existing one.
>
> If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If
>   you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can
>   right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as
>   soon as possible. In addition, your communication through higher-level
>   APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy.
>   If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement,
>   an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure
>   domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.

[Apple's WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html)  on Networking with NSURLSession also mentions ATS

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation that the setup is correct. So I've done further testing and 5s 9.2, 6+ 9.2 emulators block access with the above settings. I also tried loading images from another domain (freeimageslive.com) and got the same results.